# Open pdf with electron-pdf-window

Tags: jquery, electron

I have a web application developed with HTML and jQuery and, through Electron, becomes a desktop application (.exe file).
Using jQuery, I would like to open the pdf file.

First, I get the url of the pdf with:

```
var url = $(this).attr('href').replace(/%20/g, " ");
```

At this point I should open the file in a new window of electron, probably using [electron-pdf-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-pdf-window).
How do I run this command in jQuery?

With something like:

```
var {PDFWindow} = require('electron-pdf-window')
var win = new PDFWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
})
```

Thanks in advance